# "Windows Storage" reports much more disk usage than Folder Properties

Tags: amazon-ec2, iis, windows-server-2016, diskmanagement

My IIS inetpub folder says it's using 2.52 Gb (2.64 Gb on disk) but when I analyse disk usage with Windows Storage it says the folder is 60.0 Gb.

Why is this happening and how can I get my 57.36 Gb back?

I'm running Windows Server 2016 on Amazon EC2 and I've had to up-size the server volume three times now.  My fear is that it'll fill up, the web-apps will die, and I won't be able to connect to the server again.

I'm deleting the log files automatically with this scheduled task:
`forfiles: /p "C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles" /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c Del @path" /d -2/p "C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles" /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c Del @path" /d -30`

[screenshot showing disk usage 60.0 Gb vs 2.52 Gb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvZn5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - two issues:

1. I was logging in as someone within the "Administrators" group but not the "Administrator" - when I did, the Folder Properties matched the Windows Settings, Storage value
2. The script I was using to delete the old log entries was insufficient - see *Delete Old Log Files by Script* at on Microsoft's *[Managing IIS Log File Storage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/provisioning-and-managing-iis/managing-iis-log-file-storage#delete-old-log-files-by-script)* page for the correct script to run